# Why doesnt my simple javascript rollover work?

Tags: javascript, image, onmouseover, rollover

Hi guys I have a simple rollover onmouseover effect, I have tried several scripts but none of them work, can anyone tell me why?`

javascript:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
<!--
if (document.images) {
    homebuttonup = new Image();
    homebuttonup.src = "./images/gym-light.png";
    homebuttondown = new Image();
    homebuttondown.src = "./images/buttonright.png";
}

function buttondown(buttonname) {
    if (document.images) {
        document[buttonname].src = eval(buttonname + "down.src");
    }
}

function buttonup(buttonname) {
    if (document.images) {
        document[buttonname].src = eval(buttonname + "up.src");
    }
}
// -->
</script>
```

and link:

```
    <a href="index.html" onmouseover="buttondown('homebutton')"       onmouseout="buttonup('homebutton')">
  <img id='Img4Inner' name="homebutton" src='./images/gym-light.png' alt="" />

  </a>
```

Comment: install firebug and report back with the errors, if any

Comment: Works fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/ETHaM/. Do you have other code that might be interfering?

Comment: You may have already heard this, but use `eval` _very_ carefully. Some even argue that it should never be used. There are usually better ways to solve the problem.

Comment: I tried my code on jsfiddle and your right it does work on there.. but it doesnt work on my website any other reasons why it wouldnt? it is the little bike logo on viifit.com if you view source you would see that its in there..

Comment: I tried installing firebug but I don't think I get any errors

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ETHaM/5/

I have tried it on here and it works.. but not in my index when I open it up from my directory or when I upload it on my host.. its live on viifit.com the image with the bike (icon green one) has that exact code connected to it - the link works but not the mouseover?

Comment: I think I realized the images are within a div, how would I access such div? is document.images wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE 2 (last one lol) ** 
you currently have the onmouseout and onmouseover on the a tag, move them to the image tag and it will work:

you're code:

```
<a onmouseout="buttonup('homebutton')" onmouseover="buttondown('homebutton')"        
href="http://www.[...].com" style="height:120px;width:100px;">
<img id="Img4Inner" alt="" src="http://[..].com/images/gym-light.png" name="homebutton">
</a>
```

Working code:

```
<a onmouseout="buttonup('homebutton')" onmouseover="buttondown('homebutton')"        
href="http://www.[...].com" style="height:120px;width:100px;">
 <img alt="" src="http://[...]/images/gym-light.png"  onmouseout="buttonup(this)" 
     onmouseover="buttondown(this)" name="homebutton" id="Img4Inner">
</a>
```

**Update**: because you're invoking the functions on the anchor tags they need to have a height and a width similar to the following (place your height and width accordingly):

```
<a style="height:25px;width:25px;" href="http://www.[...].com" 
onmouseover="buttondown('homebutton')" onmouseout="buttonup('homebutton')">
...
</a>
```

and I"m out...

I just used firebug, edited the HTML with the height and width and it worked fine :

[image])

and while I"m sure that will solve the problem.. the doctype is set to <!doctype html> and should be something like what's here ([LINK](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_doctype.asp))

if you would've implemented the below approach, the image would have a height and width, and since that is the image that is being targeting, might make more sense..

http://jsfiddle.net/ETHaM/2/

```
if (document.images) {
    homebuttonup = new Image();
    homebuttonup.src = "http://www.placekitten.com/100/100/";
    homebuttondown = new Image();
    homebuttondown.src = "http://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff";
}

function buttondown(obj) {
    if (document.images) {
        obj.src = eval(obj.name+ "down.src");
    }
}

function buttonup(obj) {
    if (document.images) {
        obj.src = eval(obj.name + "up.src");
    }
}


<a href="index.html">
<img id='Img4Inner' onmouseover="buttondown(this)" onmouseout="buttonup(this)" name="homebutton" src='http://www.placekitten.com/100/100/' alt="" />
</a>
```

Comment: @mplungjan i changed my answer, just offered an alternative.. maybe its still irrelevant..

Comment: Much better. Now get rid of the eval

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ETHaM/5/

I have tried it on here and it works.. but not in my index when I open it up from my directory or when I upload it on my host.. its live on viifit.com the image with the bike (icon green one) has that exact code connected to it - the link works but not the mouseover?

Comment: @user1250526 - it's your anchor tags.. they need a height and width

Comment: Sadly with that it still doesn't work, but it does work if I put this code in a blank page, the images are within a div may that be why? in the bottom post in this thread: http://www.phpfreaks.com/forums/index.php?topic=357975.0 is the whole code I am using..

Comment: @user1250526 - did you put a height and width on the anchor tags, cause i didnt see them on your site.. and it totally works.. also, you need a standard doctype in there not <!doctype html>(http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_doctype.asp), which is probably the root of the problem.. bro.. my times expensive..

Comment: I tryed it on my machine, because it didnt work I didnt upload it.. but I have no uploaded it with height and width in anchor tags, and changed the doctype but it still doesnt work.. I dont understand how you did get it to work on my website? ive now uploaded the version with height and width but like I said still not working..

Comment: @user1250526 i can edit the html in my browser with firebug.. and you're close.. you have to move the javascript functions to the image tag now and you're good to go..

Comment: @user1250526 - I've fixed your code and posted the solution.. I will not be participating further.

Comment: No worries, thanks either way but I found another way around it today and it works! there was probably too much code interfering, I do really appreciate your help!!

Answer (score 0):

Your code works

Here is however a more unobtrusive version

http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/927nN/

```
<a href="index.html" id="homeLink"><img
 id='Img4Inner' class="hoverImg"
 name="homebutton" src='http://www.placekitten.com/100/100/' alt="" /></a>
 <a href="about.html" id="aboutLink"><img
 id='Img5Inner' class="hoverImg"
 name="aboutbutton" src='http://www.placekitten.com/100/100/' alt="" /></a>
```

```
var buttons={};
if (document.images) {
    buttons["homebuttonup"] = new Image();
    buttons["homebuttonup"].src = "http://www.placekitten.com/100/100/";
    buttons["homebuttondown"] = new Image();
    buttons["homebuttondown"].src = "http://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff";
    buttons["aboutbuttonup"] = new Image();
    buttons["aboutbuttonup"].src = "http://www.placekitten.com/100/100/";
    buttons["aboutbuttondown"] = new Image();
    buttons["aboutbuttondown"].src = "http://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff";
}

window.onload=function() {
    var images = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
    for (var i=0,n=images.length;i<n;i++) {
        if (images[i].className=="hoverImg") {
            images[i].parentNode.onmouseover=function() {
              var buttonname=this.id.replace("Link","button");
              document[buttonname].src = buttons[buttonname + "down"].src;
            }
            images[i].parentNode.onmouseout=function() {
              var buttonname=this.id.replace("Link","button");
              document[buttonname].src = buttons[buttonname + "up"].src;
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: This also doesn't work, it does great on jfiddle but not in my script, I think because the images are within a certain div, do I need to access the div instead of document.images?